# Django list matching with if == statement

Tags: django

I'm hoping this is super simple.  I just started playing around with Django for fun and have been playing around with making a search engine.

I'm setting a temporary list in a `views.py` file so I set it like this:

```
tempsearch_list = Name.objects.filter(
    Q(name__iexact='Name Not Found')
)
```

Later in my code I want to see if it's the same as I originally set so I'm trying to do this:

```
if tempsearch_list == 'Name Not Found':
```

This never matches.  Even if I put it as the next statement after I set it.  What am I doing wrong here.  This has to be super simple.  I've been trying different things for more time than I'd like to admit.

Comment: What you're doing there makes `tempsearch_list` a queryset, not a string. So that's right, `tempsearch_list == 'Name Not Found'` won't ever be `True`, because it's not a string.

Comment: `tempsearch_list` is a `QuerySet` (btw your naming is confusing because it's not a `list`). It can't be equal to a string. Try something like `tempsearch_list.first().name == 'Name Not Found'`). Also try following an introductory Django tutorial first to learn about fundamentals.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'll change the name.  I guess the true question is how to validate the query set has not changed.  I don't have a first.  I only have name.

Answer (score 0):

you filtered the objects as `tempsearch_list = Name.objects.filter(Q(name__iexact='Name Not Found'))` and later on you when you want to compare if `tempsearch_list` equals to `Name Not Found`, you don't need any **if statment** just use `if tempsearch_list.exists()`.

`tempsearch_list.exists()` will **return** `True` if there was an object named `Name Not Found` else it **returns** `False`

> how do I check the query set is still equal to the original way it was set

The queryset(`tempsearch_list`) won't changed unless you reassign it,  and that would be always update in case of adding, editing or removing a `Name`. but again if you wondering, you can compare it with fresh queryset as `if tempsearch_list == Name.objects.filter(Q(name__iexact='Name Not Found'))`

Comment: Later in the code I perform unions with the query set.  So I can't just check if it exist.  I guess the real question is how do I check the query set is still equal to the original way it was set.

Comment: just updated the answer, I hope it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I appreciate everyone who responded.  I think this helped a lot.  Here's what I did for now.  There's probably a better way to do this but it works

```
    tempsearch_queryset1 = Name.objects.filter(
        Q(name__iexact='Name Not Found')
    )
    tempsearch_queryset2 = Name.objects.filter(
        Q(name__iexact='Name Not Found')
    )
    if set(tempsearch_queryset1) == set(tempsearch_queryset2):
```

Note.  Without the set commands it does not work.  This doesn't work:

```
    tempsearch_queryset1 = Name.objects.filter(
        Q(name__iexact='Name Not Found')
    )
    tempsearch_queryset2 = Name.objects.filter(
        Q(name__iexact='Name Not Found')
    )
    if tempsearch_queryset1 == tempsearch_queryset2:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is compare Queryset and string (Queryset is list of model so you can access model by index and access model field by `.` like `model.name`

you can do that like

```
for tempsearch in tempsearch_list :
    if tempsearch.name == "Name Not Found":
```

You should compare Charfield like `name` field with string